# Targetting specific nested UL list with css

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to target the list of capabilities. In my css I have:

```
.skills .about {
    width: 490px;
    text-align: justify;
    line-height: 20px;
    /*letter-spacing: 0px;*/

}   

    .skills .about ul li {
        display: none;
    }
```

I don't know how to target that specific UL list. I need to change the `line-height` of the list to match the `line-height` of the `.skills .about` class. How would I do this?

```
<div id="about">
    <div class="aboutText">
        <h1>Who's Sam Jarvis?</h1>
        <div class="skills">
            <span class="h2span"><h2>Bio</h2></span>
            <p class="about">
                I’m a Freelance Designer currently working out of Holland Landing, Ontario. Over the last three years I’ve spent my time as a Graphic Design student at Seneca@York honing my skills and creating many of the works that are currently in my portfolio. The creative field is where I strive and though I get paid to design I also dabble in photography, illustration, playing guitar and <strong>wheeled foot maneuvers</strong>.
            </p>
            <h2>Education</h2>
            <p class="about">
                Advanced Diploma in Graphic Design
                Seneca College of Applied Arts and Technology
            </p>
            <h2>Capabilities</h2>
            <p class="about">
                <ul>
                    <li>Branding & Art Direction</li>
                    <li>Interface Design</li>
                    <li>Adobe Creative Suite</li>
                    <li>Web Standards & Accessibility</li>
                </ul>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You can't have UL inside P. Same for H2 inside SPAN.

Comment: `.skills` should be an UL element.

Comment: Use [HTML validator](http://validator.w3.org/) to check your markup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [HTML standard](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#optional-tags), the `p` element is implicitly closed before any "block level" element, including `ul`. So your markup is effectively equivalent to

```
    <h2>Capabilities</h2>
    <p class="about">
    </p><ul>
         <li>Branding & Art Direction</li>
         <li>Interface Design</li>
         <li>Adobe Creative Suite</li>
         <li>Web Standards & Accessibility</li>
    </ul>
    <p></p>
```

and the `ul` is the immediate sibling of `p.about`:

```
.about + ul { ... }
```

But wouldn't it easier just to set `.about` class to the `ul` itself?

Answer (score 0):

```
.about li {line-height: 20px}
```

Or if you want to be more specific:

```
.skills > .about li {line-height: 20px}
```